# Deleting lines between tags and inserting new lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to delete all the lines in a text file between two known tags for example `*Plasticity, dependencies=1` and `*Hardening` tags in the example below and fill new rows of data which is not always the same number of lines as the number of lines deleted.

```
 3.72e+06,  68.1857, 0.384645,     0.01,     0.01,       1., , 0.644409
 1.91e+07,  66.4193, 0.760787,     0.01,     0.01,       1., , 0.905195
*Plasticity, dependencies=1
 3.72e+06,  68.1857, 0.384645,     0.01,     0.01,       1., , 0.644409
 8.42e+06,  67.7814, 0.484645,     0.01,     0.01,       1., , 0.790209
  1.5e+07,  67.0228, 0.677347,     0.01,     0.01,       1., , 0.880479
 1.91e+07,  66.4193, 0.760787,     0.01,     0.01,       1., , 0.905195
 2.05e+07,  66.1303, 0.794057,     0.01,     0.01,       1., , 0.918807
 2.24e+07,  65.5214,  0.80324,     0.01,     0.01,       1., , 0.922274
*Hardening
 1.5e+07,  67.0228, 0.677347,     0.01,     0.01,       1., , 0.880479
 2.05e+07,  66.1303, 0.794057,     0.01,     0.01,       1., , 0.918807
*Cleaning
```

For example, I wish to insert following lines between the two tags afterward

```
 1.67e+07,  67.0228, 0.77347,     0.01,     0.01,       1., , 0.80479
 1.81e+07,  66.4193, 0.70787,     0.01,     0.01,       1., , 0.95195
 6.05e+07,  66.1303, 0.894057,     0.01,     0.01,       1., , 0.98807
```

I can see some examples in other answers but none of them guide me to how to insert new rows/lines after deleting all the unwanted lines. I wish to do something line delete all between tags and fill new ones I have between those tags.

Comment: The most pythonic way begins with writing some code to try and solve your problem.

Comment: How large are the files? Are you able to read them into memory entirely?

Comment: Chrisz, I did try but nothing gave an useful output to post with my query. @ToddW Files are not so big, few MB mostly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to read each line of the file into a list. Then find the index of the first list item to remove and the last list item to remove and use `del[first:last+1]` to remove those, then use `list.insert()` to put in the new rows starting at `first`.